# MediaMetadataRetriever throws RuntimeException in Android 11

Tags: android, android-11

I'm trying to get a frame from a video with MediaMetadataRetriever and just in Android 11 the function `MetadataRetriever.setDataSource(path: String)` is throwing an exception like this:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0xFFFFFFEA
```

I've noticed that in Android 11, in that function this info has been added: `The path, or the URI (doesn't support streaming source currently) of the input media file.`

does it mean that video files in MediaMetadataRetriever are not supported anymore in Android 11??

Comment: Please share the solution if it is resolved at your end.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution. I hope it helps, use MetadataRetriever as follows

```
inputStream = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
retriever.setDataSource(inputStream.getFD());
```